# Can't access Tomcat webapp in local network using hostname, but it's ok using ip (on Android device)

Tags: tomcat, lan, hostname

I have a computer with Tomcat 9 running and I'm trying to access a webapp from a mobile phone connected to the same network using wifi. There is no problem if I access it using the ip (192.168.1.49:8080/MyApp) but I get an error when trying to do it using the hostname (MY-PC:8080/MyApp).

Accessing it with another computer connected via ethernet works both by the ip and the hostname. (EDIT:Also I have tried to disconnect the Ethernet wire and do the same using the WIFI and it works, too. So it seems it is a problem just when using a mobile device, BTW it is an Android device)

Can anyone help me?

Thank you,

Neus

Comment: Have you debugged your dns-query? What does it show when you ping MY-PC? What error are you getting?

Comment: When doing a ping from the Android device it says unknown host MY-PC. But doing a ping from another computer in the same wifi network gives a correct response

Comment: This a name-resolve issue. You have to either setup your dns or add this name to a hostsfile. Maybe check https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-a-dns-server/ first if you have no idea what a dns server is.